# How to calculate this integral using the residue theorem?

Tags: integration, residue-calculus, laurent-series

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int \limits _\gamma \sin ^2\frac{1}{\xi}\,d\xi$

$\gamma (t)=Re^{it}$,
$R>0$,
$0\leq t\leq 2\pi$

Could you help me solve this equation? I did not understand this topic very well, I managed to get the result but using a different method.

The value of the integral is 0, what is asked of me is to justify why it is 0.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain "sen"? Is it a typo for $\sin$?

Comment: Would you like to share your method with us?

Comment: if it is "sin", sorry, more than a typing error it was a language error

Comment: @paulgarrett "sen" is the Spanish abbreviation for sine (seno, coseno, y tangente).

Comment: Hint: if an analytic function is even in a deleted neighbourhood of $0$, what can you say about its Laurent series about $0$?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for explaining to me that, indeed, "sen" is "sin" ... not in English.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, what is asked of me is the demonstration of why it is worth 0, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use Residue Theorem, why not try and calculate the residue at $z=0$ (coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in the Laurent Series expansion)?

Notice that the function has only one singularity at $z=0$ and is holomorphic inside the punctured disc $0<|z|\leq R \,,R>0$ . That is it is holomorphic inside the disc at all points but at $z=0$. Hence by Cauchy's Residue Theorem we have $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\sin^{2}(\frac{1}{z})\,dz =2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}_{z=0}$
$\sin^{2}(\frac{1}{z})$.

But $\sin^{2}(\frac{1}{z})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\bigg(1-\cos(\frac{2}{z})\bigg)$

The Laurent Series expansion is then $\frac{1}{2}(1-(1-\frac{1}{2!}(\frac{2}{z})^{2}+...))$ (By using the Taylor expansion for $\cos(z)$) which should directly tell you that the residue at $z=0$ (coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in the expression above) is $0$.

Hence the integral $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\sin^{2}(\frac{1}{z})\,dz =2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}_{z=0}= 0 $ by the Residue Theorem.

Note:- $\displaystyle\cos(z)=1-\frac{z^{2}}{2!}+\frac{z^{4}}{4!}-...=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{r}z^{2r}}{(2r)!}$